# Add active class on SlideToggle nag

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu, nav

I'm trying to edit this chunk of code to add an "active" class on the element I clicked, and automatically remove it when I click on another item of my nav...

```
    var firstTime = true;
    $("#nav a").click(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $(this).addClass( "active", "fast", "easeOutBounce" );
    if (!firstTime) {
        if ($(".slid").hasClass(divname)) {
            firstTime = true;
            $(".slid").removeClass("slid").slideUp();
        } else {

            $(".slid").removeClass('slid').slideUp(500, function() {
                $("." + divname).slideToggle().addClass("slid");

            });
        }
    } else {
        $("." + divname).slideDown().addClass("slid");
        firstTime = false;
    }

});
```

Where should I add a .removeClass("active") to make this work...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var firstTime = true;
    $("#nav a").click(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass( "active", "fast", "easeOutBounce" );
    if (!firstTime) {
        if ($(".slid").hasClass(divname)) {
            firstTime = true;
            $(".slid").removeClass("slid").slideUp();
            $('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        } else {

            $(".slid").removeClass('slid').slideUp(500, function() {
                $("." + divname).slideToggle().addClass("slid");


            });
        }
    } else {
        $("." + divname).slideDown().addClass("slid");
        firstTime = false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Works great! Thx, the only thing is if I click again on the same nav item, the subnav slideUp, but the .active stays...

http://intelia.steveforest.com/

Comment: The code you are running on you site right now is a bit different in the way it retrieves the selected item to remove the class.

Comment: `$('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');` will remove all active classes before adding the new one to all the items in the #nav

Comment: Still the same... Works if I switch from one item to another, but if I click on the same nav item... the active class stays

Comment: I think i understand when you "click again" to hide the sub list you also want to remove the active class... right?

Comment: Yeah, if I clicked on "Why Intelia", and I click again on "Why Intelia" to hide it, I want to remove the active class on it.

Comment: Just test for egality like if($(this) != $('.active')) before to addClass

Comment: You need to remove the class after you slide up... check updated could be wrong and the `$('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');` could have to go in under the other slide up...

Answer (score 0):

Just do that

```
var firstTime = true;
$("#nav a").click(function() {
var divname = this.name;
//Remove existing 'active' class
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass( "active", "fast", "easeOutBounce" );
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think the best way to do it is to check if it is active and, only in that case, change active element.

This way your solution will be more performant.

```
if (this.className.indexOf('active') == -1) {
    //remove class from actual selected
    var selected = $('#nav a.active');
    selected.removeClass( "active").text('');
    // add class here
    $(this).addClass( "active", "fast", "easeOutBounce" );
    $(this).text('active');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass( "active").text('');
}
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/6LHd9/27/) a functioning example

Comment: @Steve Forest I improved my solution to best fit your problem. Try my code on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/6LHd9/24/)

Comment: I tried your solution (removed the .text though, I don't want to change the link text) but if I click on the same menu item I clicked first to hide sub nav, the a still have the active class on it... You can have a look at the link I provided before http://intelia.steveforest.com/

Comment: So you want to toggle **active** class when click on selected elements? I didn't understand. Please find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/6LHd9/27/) the updated code